# Trying to make a 2 planed 3-d space using image planes -- but having problems with weird shadow castings

Tags: image, shadows

Not the best or series 3-d person with blender. I get by with much head bashing and teeth nashing...
But i think somethings have changed with Newest Blender. I am having this weird shadow casting with two 2-d Image Planes. How do i get rid of the shadows. Trying to create a semi-3-d effect with part of the image on the ground and other half rises vertically so you can create a motion/tilt up effect.
Any ideas on how or what i am doing wrong. Been playing with Shaders and nothing is working. I've added a picture of a test render for everyone can see what i am talking about. [image: Image of Blender 3.2 Test Render illustrating shadow problem with 2 image planes]
Thanks! Calvin

Comment: sorry... but i finally figured out what the problem is. There is a function in the Shader that allows for casting shadows. I turned it off and **Poof**, the problem is now gone. Now i have another issue -- or not-- i will have to use another computer with better Graphics card to see if this is the solution. Too Damn Many Check Boxes, Add-ons, special modules and subsections!! And yeah... maybe a stomping huge monster CPU/GPU would help.
Cheers. Calvin